# How to get package name of media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is it possible to get the package name of music player when hearing the song. i am having plenty of third party music players in my devices, once i play the song from any of the devices, want to get the package name of music player. i am new to this topic, if the question does'nt make any sense pls let me know what the mistake is. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the currently active package name and activity name using the following code,

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);



                // get the info from the currently running task
                List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

                Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                        + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Package ::"
                        + componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score -2):

yes you can get the package name of any app that you want.. so start that player and see the logcate there you can see **Activity Manager** tag  and see 
Displayed com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller/.AdvancedTaskKiller: +3s38ms in **description** 
may it help you..

Answer (score -3):

You can get Package Name in below way.

```
 Context context;

context.getPackageName();//using this line in your program you can get your package name
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to get active music player package name.

Comment: this way you can get package name of your app not other app ... so try with i have describe below